# Mathics Mac installation

Tags: macos, installation, operating-system, mathics

Hello i have builted my own version of mathics (https://github.com/mathics/Mathics) based on python3 and I install on my machine ( am using ubuntu ) by typing on terminal

```
python3 setup.py --help install
```

where the setup.py of mathics is located .
Now i want to send to my instructor my version of mathics but he is using Mac os X .
Is the procedure same ? by assuming he has python3 installed .
Is there any specific instruction for him to send him ?

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Installing from github source isn't recommended unless you are a developer. (And if you were a developer you probably wouldn't be asking the question.)

When you go to the github link you cited, you'll see a list of versions and packages for [Mathics from repology.org](https://repology.org/project/mathics/versions)

Many of these are old. However if you install from [docker on dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/mathicsorg/mathics) you'll get a fairly recent version.